# Error in using "helm-projectile-find-file"

Tags: package, projectile, commands, helm-projectile

This is my config in init.el:

`(require 'helm-projectile)
(projectile-global-mode)
(setq projectile-completion-system 'helm)
(helm-projectile-on)
(setq projectile-indexing-method 'alien)
(setq projectile-switch-project-action 'helm-projectile-find-file)`

I was told "Find: incorrect argument formatting" and failed to list any file when used 'helm-projectile-find-file'.  I found that this error tips was produced by “find.exe”. However, this command works normally in a project which is considered project by default.

[image]

Comment: os? emacs version? other information?

Comment: win7 pro, GNU Emacs 24.5.1 (i686-pc-mingw32). I use el-get to manage packages, and all the packages installed are up-to-date.

Comment: Windows has its own find.exe. You need tell projectile to use find.exe from cygwin or msys2. I don't use projectile. That's all I can help

Comment: Thanks! By your hint, I found it was because projectile used the find.exe from OS which is expected the one from git.